# Remove default styles of Jquery Chosen using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we remove some styles of Jquery Chosen using Jquery or javascript. I want to remove 'top : 100%' attribute from 'chosen-drop' class. I tried `$('.ddlDpndtRsrc').find('.chosen-container .chosen-drop').css('top','');` but it is not working.

```
<div class="controlsDiv ddlDpndtRsrc">
    <select data-placeholder="Select" id="ddlDependentResource" name="dependent_resource" data-col="DependentResource" class="infoInput chsnddl" style="display: none;">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="3">Business visa</option>

    </select>
    <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 90%;" title="" id="ddlDependentResource_chosen"><a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1"><span>Select</span><div><b></b></div></a>
        <div class="chosen-drop" style="top: 0px;">
            <div class="chosen-search">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <ul class="chosen-results">
                <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Business visa</li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your html also.

Comment: That should work, cannot help more unless you share the code. Thanks.

Comment: edit your post and add the HTML.

Comment: I can see that your <div> is not properly closed in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

After making your HTML post above readable, what you have provided should work, ensure `.chosen-container .chosen-drop` doesn't already have `!important` overriding the `top` value.

It may be a good idea to get used to replacing `<b>` with `<strong>` also :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="ddlDpndtRsrc">
        <div class="chosen-container chosen-drop">
          Dummy text
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var element = $('.ddlDpndtRsrc').find('.chosen-container.chosen-drop');
    element.css({
      'top' : '0%'
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/niyadi/3/watch